# Access UINavigationController issue(Swift)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I am making a log in app.
My initial view controller is a log in interface,and here if username and password it's ok you click the "Log In" button and it shows up my navigation controllers root viewcontroller.My nav controller has a slide out menu.In this slide out menu I have a UITableView with 3 rows and if I click on the rows one shows up a red viewcontroller which also has the slide out menu and like this,so everything works fine.
But I also have in my app that if you are not a member yet,you can sign up.You click the sign up button,write your infos and stuff,and finally you have to press the sign up button to validate your informations and open up the same nav controllers root controller as when you press the "Log In" button.
It opens it up,you can also open the slide out menu by sliding from left to right,but here comes the issue.The options(rows) that I have in my slide out menu doesn't work.I can tap on every row of the table view in the slide out menu,but nothing happens.How can I fix this?

Because as you see,everything works fine when I open up the nav controller from the initial view controller,but when I open another view controller from the initial viewcontroller,and that from that second viewcontroller the nav controller,it doesn't work.Help me please!

Comment: Without seeing code, this is a very vague question. My suggestion: determine everything you do differently between the two cases (and try to minimize those differences as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

just put both viewcontrollers individual uinavigationcontrollers

Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It still doesn't work.So look how I have.I have FirstViewController,SecondViewController and a NavigationController with it's root view controller.My initial view controller is FirstViewController and I have implemented in the NavigationController a slide out menu.So my app starts and I have a button which when is pressed access the NavigationController and everything works fine.But I also have another button on the FirstViewController which when is pressed accesses the SecondViewController.Than on the SecondViewController I have a button which takes me back to the FirstViewController and after if I press that button on the FirstViewController which takes me to the NavigationController it takes me,shows up the NavigationController but the slide out menu doesn't work.:( I don't know whats the problem:-??